# Nginx listen to NOT port 80

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have read many issues here on NGINX where in it does not listen to port 80, but my problem is different. NGINX listens to my default port 80 but when I try to change the Listen 81, so that NGINX will listen to any request coming from port 81 it does not give me any response.

Anyways here's what I did.
1.) I create a config file inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/myportconfig
2.) then I created a symlink like so ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myportconfig /etch/nginx/sites-enable/
3.) I did not modify anything in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
4.) And lastly here's the content of my myportconfig

```
    server {                
        listen 81;
        root /mysites/sites1.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name 10.100.100.10;

        if ($request_uri ~* ^(/welcome(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
        {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
        }
        # remove trailing "index" from all controllers
        if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
        }


        if (!-d $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /mysites/sites1.com$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # Restrict .git directories
        location ~ /\.git {
                deny all;
        }

        # Restrict all project directories
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Also take note that when using only port 80 the sites load just fine. BUt when I change to different port then it does not load any page... am I missing something guys? please help...

I also tried doing netstat with

```
netstat -lnp | grep 8
```

and it gives me this output

```
   tcp   0   0.0.0.0:81        0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN
   udp   0   0.0.0.0:68        0.0.0.0:*
```

I also tried doing telnet inside the server

```
   telnet 10.100.100.10 81
```

and here's the response

```
    Trying 10.100.100.10
connected to 10.100.100.10
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I `telnet` on my local computer

```
    telnet 10.100.100.10 81
Connecting To 10.100.100.10....Could not open connection to the host, on port 81:
Connection failed
```

Hope someonne can help me with this. What I would like to do is access my site using different port and not using port 80

Comment: Have you added the rules for port 81 in the AWS security group?

Comment: where is it mentioned that NGINX sits on AWS?

Comment: Sorry if I failed to mentioned that Its an instance of AWS. But I found out that Tan Hong Tat idea was kinda of a similar solution to the problem. I found out that all access coming outside the server are being blocked except for request of port 80 and 443. Thanks again for the reply guys

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I failed to mentioned that Its an instance of AWS. But I found out that Tan Hong Tat idea was kinda of a similar solution to the problem. I found out that all access coming outside the server are being blocked except for request of port 80 and 443. Thanks again for the reply guys – Madzmar Ullang